# Loop(repetição) HTML/PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde,
Estou com um problema de repetição em meu código. Queria saber se existe alguma forma de diminuir o código que está muito extenso devido a isso. Segue código:

```
<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=<?php echo $nova[0]?>&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);"><?php echo ($newuasg[0] . "/" . $newuasg[1])?></a> 
<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=<?php echo $nova[1]?>&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);"><?php echo ($newuasg[2] . "/" . $newuasg[3])?></a> 
<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=<?php echo $nova[2]?>&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);"><?php echo ($newuasg[4] . "/" . $newuasg[5])?></a> 
<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=<?php echo $nova[3]?>&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);"><?php echo ($newuasg[6] . "/" . $newuasg[7])?></a> 
<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=<?php echo $nova[4]?>&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);"><?php echo ($newuasg[8] . "/" . $newuasg[9])?></a>
```

Essa é só uma parte do código que se repete nesse mesmo padrão por mais 2000 linhas. 
Meu problema está nas varáveis, $nova e $newuasg. Desde já agradeço.

Utilizei a resposta do @Vitor Carnaval e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua intenção é manter a arquitetura desse arrays e printá-los você pode utilizar a seguinte solução que possui variáveis bem explícitas:

```
$par = 0;
$impar = 1;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($nova); $i++) {
    echo '<a href="https://www.comprasnet.gov.br/pregao/fornec/Acompanhar1.asp?prgCod=' . $nova[$i] . '&pagina=1&botao=T" target="inframe" onclick="mostrarAtivo(this);">' . $newuasg[$par] . '/' . $newuasg[$impar] . '</a><br>'; 
    $par = $par + 2;
    $impar = $impar + 2;
}
```